# fouriernc vs. fourier

Tags: fonts, fourier

As far as I can tell from the documentation, `\usepackage{fouriernc}` should set up NC Schoolbook, from the `fourier` package, as the front for the main text with a suitable font for math. So I expect a document that does not contain any math to look the same with `\usepackage{fouriernc}` and `\usepackage{fourier}`.

But in fact, they look similar; with `fouriernc` the font is a bit thicker and wider… Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite the contrary, in fact: `fouriernc` uses the NewCentury Schoolbook fonts for your text, and the Fourier fonts (designed by Michel Bovani) for your maths.

If you load the `fourier` package, it's the Utopia fonts which will be used for the text: the Fourier fonts are in fact math fonts which have been designed to complement the Utopia (text) fonts.

So it is quite normal that your 100 % text document looks different with each package. One uses New Century Schoolbook and the other Utopia.

Comment: Thanks! Confusing names… Is there a “proper” with witch I set the text to New Century Schoolbook, when I do not care about the math font?

Comment: `\usepackage{newcent}` or `\usepackage{tgschola}`, if I remember correctly. But `\usepackage{fouriernc}` does the job as well: it won't complain if you don't use the math fonts. ;-)